# How do I add another array to a set, specifically a string?

Tags: c, cs50

This is a bit of a follow-up to the last post I made on here, now asking how to add another string array to my previous text-based item shop. Someone was very helpful last time, telling me I could keep track of prices and item names via arrays, which while I still don't fully understand, am trying to make use of. I should also preface that my code is extremely simple, since I'm just barely starting with programming.

My code is the following,

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_to_price(string item)
{
    //The array/s that's catching me up.
    string items[] = { "Matchbox", "Wool Hat", "Heavy Coat", "Canned Food" };
    int prices[] = { 50, 125, 250, 25 };
    string description[] = { "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm.\n", "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!\n", "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!\n", "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!" };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof items / sizeof *items); i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(items[i], item))
        {
            return prices [i];
        }
    }
    //Item not available
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Dialogue, then ask for item selection
    int buckaroonies = 500;
    printf("Hey chum, welcome to the item shop. You've got a handful 'o coin on ya, huh?\nYou came to the right place, we got the best wares in town!\n\n");
    printf("Store:\n\nMatchbox - 50\nWool Hat - 125\nHeavy Coat - 250\nCanned Food - 25\n");
    string select = get_string ("What'll it be? You have %i buckaroonies, pal.\n", buckaroonies);

    //Get item price from selection
    int price = string_to_price(select);

    //Return dialogue based on selected item.
    if (-1 == price)
    {
        printf("We aint got that, pal.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char c = get_char ("That %s'll cost ya %i buckaroonies. %s You want it?\n", select, price, description);
    }
}
```

I'm surely doing something wrong, because I'm getting an error telling me "description" isn't a declared string.

Comment: Your database arrays (probably you do not know structs yet so I will not use them) have to be not to be local to the function which searches for price

Comment: If you want to add some new products and you did not learn about dynamic memory allocation you need to have larger arrays (with "empty slots" which you will fill with new products data)

Comment: @Alex The array description is not declared in main where it is used. Move its declaration from the function to main.

Comment: @gulpr It's not about adding a new product to the menu, I'm trying to add another thing that is returned. Like how inputting the name of the item would return the item and the price, I'm trying to also make it return an additional string containing a short description of the item.

Comment: @Alex Dcelare a structure that contains data members  item, price and description and declare an array of this structure.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm not really sure what that means, so I guess I'm a little in over my head for now. I'm going to do some more research and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays (`items`, `prices`, `description`) are *local* to the `string_to_price` function - meaning they can only be accessed inside that function. `main` can't see them. There are a couple of fixes.

Also, the function should probably return the index, not the price so you can access the other arrays.

Make the arrays global:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string items[] = { "Matchbox", "Wool Hat", "Heavy Coat", "Canned Food" };
int prices[] = { 50, 125, 250, 25 };
string description[] = { "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm.\n", "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!\n", "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!\n", "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!" };
const size_t num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);

int find_item(string item)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items ; i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(items[i], item))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //Item not available
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Dialogue, then ask for item selection
    int buckaroonies = 500;
    printf("Hey chum, welcome to the item shop. You've got a handful 'o coin on ya, huh?\nYou came to the right place, we got the best wares in town!\n\n");
    printf("Store:\n\nMatchbox - 50\nWool Hat - 125\nHeavy Coat - 250\nCanned Food - 25\n");
    string select = get_string ("What'll it be? You have %i buckaroonies, pal.\n", buckaroonies);

    //Find item from selection
    int index = find_item(select);

    //Return dialogue based on selected item.
    if (-1 == item)
    {
        printf("We aint got that, pal.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char c = get_char ("That %s'll cost ya %i buckaroonies. %s You want it?\n", items[index], prices[index], description[index]);
    }
}
```

Since global values are frowned on, another option is to make them local to `main` and pass as a parameter:

```
int find_item(string item, string items[], size_t num_items)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items; i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(items[i], item))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //Item not available
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    string items[] = { "Matchbox", "Wool Hat", "Heavy Coat", "Canned Food" };
    int prices[] = { 50, 125, 250, 25 };
    string description[] = { "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm.\n", "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!\n", "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!\n", "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!" };
    const size_t num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);

    //Dialogue, then ask for item selection
    int buckaroonies = 500;
    printf("Hey chum, welcome to the item shop. You've got a handful 'o coin on ya, huh?\nYou came to the right place, we got the best wares in town!\n\n");
    printf("Store:\n\nMatchbox - 50\nWool Hat - 125\nHeavy Coat - 250\nCanned Food - 25\n");
    string select = get_string ("What'll it be? You have %i buckaroonies, pal.\n", buckaroonies);

    //Find item from selection
    int index = find_item(select, items, num_items);

    //Return dialogue based on selected item.
    if (-1 == index)
    {
        printf("We aint got that, pal.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char c = get_char ("That %s'll cost ya %i buckaroonies. %s You want it?\n", items[index], prices[index], description[index]);
    }
}
```

Eventually, you will learn structs, which will allow you to keep the data together.

```
struct item {
    string name;
    int price;
    string description;
};

int find_item(string item_name, struct item items[], size_t num_items)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items ; i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(items[i].name, item_name))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //Item not available
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
   struct item items[] = {
        {"Matchbox", 50, "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm."},
        {"Wool Hat", 125, "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!"},
        {"Heavy Coat", 250, "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!"},
        {"Canned Food", 25, "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!"}
    };
    const size_t num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);

    //Dialogue, then ask for item selection
    int buckaroonies = 500;
    puts("Hey chum, welcome to the item shop. You've got a handful 'o coin on ya, huh?\nYou came to the right place, we got the best wares in town!\n");
    puts("Store:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        printf("%s - %d\n", items[i].name, items[i].price);
    }
    string select = get_string ("What'll it be? You have %i buckaroonies, pal.\n", buckaroonies);

    //Find item from selection
    int index = find_item(select, items, num_items);

    //Return dialogue based on selected item.
    if (-1 == index)
    {
        puts("We aint got that, pal.");
    }
    else
    {
        char c = get_char("That %s'll cost ya %i buckaroonies. %s You want it?\n", items[index].name, items[index].price, items[index].description);
    }
}
```

Comment: this was very helpful. i'm looking to learn more about structs in the future, they seem very convenient!